# POST request to API created by lambda function in amazon AWS in python works good in postman but not in reactjs code

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda

I have written the following code in my react js file, in the place of URL there is my AWS link.

```
const { empid, name, author } = body;
  const onInputChange = e => {
    setUser({ ...body, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }; 
 const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post(url, body);
    history.push("/");
    console.log(body);
  };
```

This is my error I have already added Moesif origin crops extension to my browser :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'url' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the API has CORS disabled
2. Check if there a trailing / at the end of the api that you are calling. If there a trailing / then remove it. Ex: [www.example.com/api/get_lists/](http://www.example.com/api/get_lists/) should be [www.example.com/api/get_lists](http://www.example.com/api/get_lists)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable [cors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors-console.html) on your Api Gateway resource.

Also if you are using lambda proxy you need to return cors headers from your lambda response as well.

```
return {
statusCode: 200,
body: '<response as string>', 
headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'your allowed domains', 
   ... // Other cors headers
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that the `CORS` option is not enabled on your `API Gateway Resource`.

1 - Go to your API Gateway Resource and enable `CORS`.

2 - Re `deploy` your API Gateway for the changes to take effect.